# Invalid Date in foreach

Tags: javascript, wordpress, date, foreach

I don't understand why one date is good and the rest show "Invalid Date".

[image]

[image]

```js
const blocksDate = document.querySelectorAll(".roadmap__time");
blocksDate.forEach((block) => {
  const dateString = block.innerHTML;
  const dateBlock = new Date(dateString);
  const currentDate = new Date();
  console.log(dateBlock);
});
```

```html
<span class="roadmap__time">1 maja, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">16 czerwca, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">3 marca, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">3 lipca 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">9 lipca 2021</span>
```

Comment: seems like it would have something to do with locale but really I'm not familiar with such things. One possibility is that maja is a valid date in a different locale (so it works) and the rest are not recognized (because polish is not the current locale). But I'm not sure that locale is even the right word here.

Comment: @topsail—parsing of unsupported formats is implementation dependent. It should have nothing to do with locale since many hosts have no idea of their location.

Comment: The dupe is not answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason 1 mar(ca) works is that the Date.parse sees only the first 3 chars and guesses March

Here is a script that converts both ways

```js
const months = ["STY", "LUT", "MAR", "KWIE", "MAJ", "CZE", "LIP", "SIE", "WRZ", "PAZ", "LIS", "GRU"]
const options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "long",
  day: "numeric"
};

const blocksDate = document.querySelectorAll(".roadmap__time");
blocksDate.forEach((block) => {
  const dateString = block.textContent.trim();
  const ddmmmyyyy = dateString.split(/[ \/]/);
  let dd, mmm, yyyy;
  if (ddmmmyyyy.length === 3) {
    dd = ddmmmyyyy[0];
    mmm = ddmmmyyyy[1]
    yyyy = ddmmmyyyy[2];
  } else {
    dd = 1;
    mmm = ddmmmyyyy[0];
    yyyy = ddmmmyyyy[1];
  }
  if (!isNaN(mmm)) mmm = months[+mmm-1]
  mmm = mmm.slice(0,3)

  console.log(dd, mmm, yyyy);
  const dateBlock = new Date(yyyy, months.indexOf(mmm.toUpperCase()), dd, 15, 0, 0, 0);
  console.log(dateBlock);
  const plDate = dateBlock.toLocaleDateString("pl", options)
  console.log(plDate)

});
```

```html
<span class="roadmap__time">1 Maja, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">16 czerwca, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">3 marca, 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">3 lipca 2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">9 lipca 2021</span>
<time class="roadmap__time"> 15/07/2022</time>
<span class="roadmap__time">marca/2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">Lipca/2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">05/2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">06/2022</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">lipca, 2021</span>
<span class="roadmap__time">lipca 2021</span>
```

Comment: How change this converts for date as m/Y?

Comment: What do you mean? what is the input you have and expected output?

Comment: I want to convert this code when I am displaying date in format ex. 05/2022.

Comment: I have date format day/month now. I would like to change this code for this format.
My issue:
Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: See update that handles "marca, 2022 ", "marca 2022", "marca/2022" or "05/2022" too

Comment: :/
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

Comment: Not here. Please give me the HTML you have

Comment: <time class="roadmap__time" datetime="15/07/2022">
15/07/2022</time>

Comment: You keep changing the rules!!!

Comment: fixed it. Now also supports normal dates

Comment: <3
God bless you!